# Not able to browse website through using domain name on IIS server

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-ec2, dns

I have got a strange problem while setting up my .NET website on `IIS server` on `Amazon EC2` instance.

I have created a new website giving its path to my website folder in `IIS 7.5`.

I have given the ip address and DNS in domain settings.

And configured the host name in bindings section of website with `www.domain.com`

I am able to browse it through the IP address but not able to browse it using domain. It is showing some service page...

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your host header in IIS. Here's how to do it on IIS 6.0 for example:

http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/

Also, does www.domain.com actually resolve to your IP address?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the A record for for the domain isn't set to the correct IP address.  Have you confirmed that the changes took AND that they've propagated to your computer?  If you ping www.domain.com, do you get the correct IP?